# HTML page submission without redirection

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit

Is there any method to submit an html form without redirecting from the current page without using ajax?

Comment: what kind of data is the form sending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set a `target=""` for your `form` - so you could submit your form to a new tab (`target="_blank"`) or to a small, hidden `iframe` (`target="nameofmyiframe"`)

Answer (score 3):

Without using ajax? An iframe. Is it recommended? No. Why can't you use ajax techniques?

Answer (score 1):

Use any element that relies on external resources.

#### If file uploading is required

Change the `target` attribute of the form to the name of some hidden iframe.

#### If file uploading isn't required

Use any element that pulls its content from an external resource

```
<img src="server.php?name=JohnDoe" />
<link href="server.php?name=JohnDoe" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="server.php?name=JohnDoe"></script>
...
```

But why can't you use AJAX? Note that it's now [possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications) to upload files with AJAX as well.

Answer (score 0):

event `onSubmit` what calling a function which end with `return false`